# Visual Studio 2017 Look For .dll In Custom Folder

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I am trying to look for `.dll` files from a folder of my choosing.

My folder structure for the project looks like this:

```
SolutionDir
|-data
 |-includes
  |-SDL2-2.0.6
   |-include
   |-lib
|-ProjectDir
 |-data
  |-sdl
   |.lib and .dll files here
 |main.cpp
```

In `Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories` I have `"$(SolutionDir)data\includes\SDL2-2.0.6\lib"`. In `Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies` I have the following:

```
data\sdl\SDL2main.lib
data\sdl\SDL2.lib
```

I believe Visual Studio 2017 is finding this perfectly fine. However, when I run the program, it can't find the `.dll` files which are included in same directory as the `.lib` files (`ProjectDir\data\sdl`).

If I move the `.dll` files to the `ProjectDir`, then the program works fine. I do not want them in there. Is there a way to tell Visual Studio to look for them in the `ProjectDir\data\sdl` folder?

Comment: I guess when you run the program from Visual Studio it works fine and when you run the program without visual studio it doesn't work. Right?

Comment: No, when I run the program from Visual Studio, it's looking for the `.dll` files in the `ProjectDir` folder instead of `ProjectDir\data\sdl`. The same result if I run without Visual Studio.

Comment: Have you tried using relative path in additional include directory?

Comment: In `C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories`? I have the following: `$(SolutionDir)data\includes\SDL2-2.0.6\include`.

Comment: Add the 'sdl' directory location in additional library directory.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still can't find  the `.dll` files after adding the sdl directory in Additional Library Directories.

Comment: Project settings in Visual Studio have no effect on locations where executable will look for `.dll`, see [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx). Typically you need to copy required .dlls into the folder where .exe is (you can perform this a custom build step) or install them globally.

Comment: This worked for me when I was developing some SDL. http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/windows/msvsnet2010u/index.php

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. Looks like there isn't an easy way to do this.

Comment: There is an easy way to do this - just copy required .dll into the folder where .exe is...

Comment: I meant easy way to specify dll paths for program.